# ActivityNotFoundException is not triggered to open a downloaded PDF file

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I want to download a PDF from a url and also want to trigger `catch` phrase if no PDF Viewer is detected.

Here's my code:

```
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(materialPdfUrl)));
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        openDialog(getString(R.string.error),
                getString(R.string.no_pdf_reader));
    }
```

Now the problem is that ActivityNotFoundException is never triggered because it always download the PDF even if there is no PDF Viewer around. How do you suggest I do this?

**EDIT:**
Here's my old code:

```
Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(materialPdfUrl));
pdfIntent.setType("application/pdf");
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(pdfIntent);
```

Comment: show me your openDialog(getString(R.string.error),
                getString(R.string.no_pdf_reader) code.

Comment: @ManishPatel My `openDialog` is similar to what is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20653259/1968739).

Answer (score 3):

```
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(materialPdfUrl)));
```

is starting an `Implicit Intent` and therefore will not throw `ActivityNotFoundException`.

If you read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ccases

> Consider, for example, what the browser application does when the user follows a link on a web page. It first tries to display the data (as it could if the link was to an HTML page). If it can't display the data, it puts together an implicit intent with the scheme and data type and tries to start an activity that can do the job. If there are no takers, it asks the download manager to download the data. That puts it under the control of a content provider, so a potentially larger pool of activities (those with filters that just name a data type) can respond.

Therefore if no PDF viewers are found the Android Download Manager will attempt to download the file (rather than throw that exception).

If you want to view the pdf or be told you cannot view it (rather than download) then you will need to query the system manually using the `PackageManager` to find out if an application will respond to your intent rather than just firing and forgetting.

---

FYI `ActivityNotFoundException` will be thrown for `Explicit Intent's` something like:

````
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.facebook","NewsFeedActivity.java"));
startActivity(intent);```
````

Comment: I also tried before, the one you mentioned `PackageManager` to detect an app that responds to my intent. [Here](http://pastebin.com/m7HvcBK8)'s the code, but surprisingly it did not detect some of the famous PDF readers (Adobe and Foxit).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the PackageManager to detect if the system will handle a PDF intent for you.

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setType("application/pdf");
List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY;
if (list.size() > 0) {
    // Happy days a PDF reader exists
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    // No PDF reader, ask the user to download one first 
    // or just open it in their browser like this
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        .setData(Uri.parse("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdfUrl);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

See this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html) for more info on checking intents. The added benefit of this approach is that you can grey out/remove menu options before the app even tries to execute the Intent. Then you can explain to the user in a slightly more friendly way that they need to grab a PDF viewer app, or indeed apply some logic to fallback to a web based PDF viewer.

Having trialled this approach with Foxit Reader and Adobe Reader they both seem to have different behaviours. Foxit will not download the PDF for you, it will redirect you to the browser and download the file. Adobe will download the file for you then display it.

So to get round this difference once you have detected that a PDF viewer is available then you will probably want to download the PDF to the SD card, for example the downloads folder. This is probably best achieved in an AsyncTask, or you might be able to use the [`DownloadManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html). Then open the local file Uri in the preferred reader. This should get round the difference in behaviour. Maybe open a ticket with Foxit to bring it into line with Adobe? ;)

Comment: This doesn't seem to detect the PDF Viewers I've installed just now because it triggered the `else` statement. What could be the problem?

Comment: Might be worth trying `setType("application/pdf")` instead of `setDataAndType()`.

Comment: Sorry for the second comment, I missed the edit window...

I've tried out setType and things seem to work, as it detects both Adobe Reader and the Kitkat supplied Quick Office.

Comment: There's no `pdfUri` so I assumed it's written like this: `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(PdfUrl)).setType("application/pdf");`. It already detected and opened Adobe and Foxit Reader but it didn't download the PDF from the url, so nothing is displayed.

Comment: The testing intent doesn't actually need the data to be set. The first intent is just looking for anything that will handle the PDF mimetype. As you say it looks like Foxit doesn't download the PDF for you, which is all kinds of rubbish. Also it doesn't look like it likes opening a Uri with the mimetype set. See my answer for a slightly more expanded solution to get round this.

Answer (score 1):

The function **startActivity()** you use is not on the condition that the PDF reader is not exist, it only download the PDF from the URL, and if there are PDF Readers then it will offer a selector, just as the function of clicking on a PDF file.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me. Actually I edited my code, I posted my old code and what happened was it **DID** triggered the `catch` phrase but it didn't download the PDF. So by the time I had I had already a PDF Viewer for example Adobe PDF Viewer, it opened Adobe but it didn't open the file since it was not download. Hence, my new code.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your device or emulator does not have an application capable of viewing a local PDF file.

Whenever you start an intent, you should have the native app installed on the emulator to handle that intent. Ex. If you invoke an intent with Maps as the action, you would have to use the Google API's based emulator. By default, android emulator does not have a PDF reader. You could test this on a device with a PDF reader and it should work fine.

Comment: Here's what happened, I have no PDF Viewer at all. But it still triggered the `try` phrase and downloaded the PDF.

Comment: I also didnot have it on my emulator. I got the acrobat opened. thanks

Answer (score 1):

you may try this code. This may helpful to you.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();


                            intent.setClassName("com.adobe.reader", "com.adobe.reader.AdobeReader");

                            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                             Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                             intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");

                                try {

                                    startActivity(intent);
                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                            getApplicationContext());
                                    builder.setTitle("No Application Found");
                                    builder.setMessage("Download application from Android Market?");
                                    builder.setPositiveButton(
                                            "Yes, Please",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(
                                                        DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int which) {
                                                    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(
                                                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                                    marketIntent.setData(Uri
                                                            .parse("market://details?id=com.adobe.reader"));
                                                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                                                    startActivity(marketIntent);
                                                }
                                            });
                                    builder.setNegativeButton("No, Thanks",
                                            null);
                                    builder.create().show();
                                }
```

Comment: This is similar to my old code, it triggered the `catch` phrase if I have no PDF Viewer and opened a Viewer if I have one. The problem is that it only opened the viewer but it did not download the PDF itself so it was not displayed. And what does this line do? (`intent.setClassName("com.adobe.reader", "com.adobe.reader.AdobeReader");`)

Comment: Yes, and if there's none it will trigger the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

use startActivityForResult(..).

[See the link here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

You will get the result in onActivityResult(..) of your activity.

Comment: It is used only when you want to have a value back from the second opened activity. thanks